# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, image, drag-and-drop, src

User should be able to drag and drop image and the only condition is images should be replaced by their position, is their any otherway I can achieve the same like without using setdata and getdata .

```js
let dragindex = 0;
let dropindex = 0;
let clone = "";

function drag(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("src", e.target.id);
  console.log(e.target.id);
}

function drop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  clone = e.target.cloneNode(true);
  let data = e.dataTransfer.getData("src");

  let nodelist = document.getElementById("imageListId").childNodes;
  console.log(nodelist);
  for (let i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i++) {
    console.log(nodelist[i]);
    if (nodelist[i].id == data) {
      dragindex = i;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(document.getElementById(data));
  console.log(e.target);
  document.getElementById("imageListId").replaceChild(document.getElementById(data), e.target);

  document.getElementById("imageListId").insertBefore(clone, document.getElementById("imageListId").childNodes[dragindex]);
}

function allowDrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

/* image dimension */
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
}

/* imagelistId styling */
#imageListId {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#imageListId div {
  margin: 0 4px 4px 4px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Output order styling */
.listitemClass {
  border: 1px solid #006400;
  width: 350px;
}

.height {
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="height"></div><br>

<div id="imageListId">
  <div id="div1" class="listitemClass" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="https://images.fastcompany.net/image/upload/w_1280,f_auto,q_auto,fl_lossy/w_596,c_limit,q_auto:best,f_auto/fc/3034007-inline-i-applelogo.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div id="div2" class="listitemClass" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div id="div3" class="listitemClass" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/24078/screenshots/15522433/media/e92e58ec9d338a234945ae3d3ffd5be3.jpg?compress=1&resize=400x300" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to drag and drop the images into different divs and the dropable div's image should be replaced by the drag image position should I be using divs as draggable and image as droppable or drag drop should only be at my divs
Thankyou for answers in advance.